# MariaDB 10.3 implicit cast of string parameter to integer column fails

Tags: mysql, mariadb

After upgrade from MariaDB 10.0.x to 10.3.x a SELECT containing a quoted integer string, like '3' is no longer implicitly cast to an INTEGER column value which results in a query failure, 1366, Incorrect integer value. Is there a way to enable implicit conversions?

A few SQL_MODE settings have been tried to address the issue but have no effect. Here's an simple example scenario.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database.tablename (
   col1 INTEGER UNSIGNED,
   col2 INTEGER UNSIGNED,
   PRIMARY KEY (col1)) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

```
INSERT INTO database.tablename VALUES (1,'2');
```

> Query failure(1366), : Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'database', 'tablename', 'col2' at row 1

I expect the query to succeed where column 2 is implicitly cast to an INTEGER UNSIGNED as occurred in MariaDB 10.0.x.

Comment: Works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=e44e83872327b157956b8f61debaa820

Comment: If I test this in mysql console, it does work. It failed, however, when the query was initiated in code through the connector. A code modification removing the 'quotes' around the integer corrects the issue. The issue does not reproduce in the mysql console for innodb and memory tables.  WIll try additional variations to see if there is a specific trigger.

Answer (score 4):

I've worked out what's happening.

Enabling the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode exposes a problem in the table definitions where a default value is not provided for an INTEGER column. This was a new issue for us in MariaDB 10.3 because of default SQL_MODE changes between MariaDB 10.0.38 and 10.3.15 that include STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. This can be corrected by removal of the flag.

Removal of the flag with MariaDB running with a connected process

set sql_mode = "";
set GLOBAL sql_mode = "";

does not change the INSERT behavior until after the connecting process is restarted and its connection to the database is reset. After this, the data type default value rules are applied and the INSERT query is performed without error.

So the issue was not with the integer datatype being quoted in the query, rather, it was that there was no integer default value for the column when STRICT_TRANS_TABLES remained enabled for the connection.

Comment: Since you provided a value, I don't understand why it needed a "default".

Comment: Putting **set sql_mode = ""** in my.cnf and restarting the service fixed the issue for us. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quick solution you can just add **set sql_mode = "";** before your query. For example -

```
set sql_mode = "";
your sql here;
```